# Reset option tag value with one from database using PHP MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Initially I am populating my option tag with Quantity available in stock.

```
<select name="quantity" class="form-control input-sm" id="quantity">
    <?php for ($i=1; $i<=$Quantity; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

**I am updating Quantity from my html form using Javascript:**

```
function update_id(id)
{
    if (confirm('Update quantity for this Item?')) {
        uid = id;
        quantity = $('select[name=quantity]').val()
        window.location.href="Cart.php?update_id="+uid+"&quantity="+quantity;//+'?quantity='+quantity;
    }   
}
```

and storing it in Cart table against that particular product. On reloading or refreshing the page, option tag gets reset to default value here as '1'. I want to assign option tag value with the Updated Quantity from DB against that particular product.

[Screenshot of the cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UwID.png)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the HTML part is coming from "Cart.php". If so, you could change it for :

```
<select name="quantity" class="form-control input-sm" id="quantity">
    <?php 
        $selectedQuantity = (isset($_GET["quantity"]) ? $_GET["quantity"] : 1);
        for ($i=1; $i<=$Quantity; $i++) { 
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"<?=($selectedQuantity == $i ? " selected" : "")?>><?php echo $i;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

So adding a "selected" attribute to the option tag valued the selected one.

Comment: I've tried your solution but without `? $_GET["quantity"] : 1)` and worked till extent of changing the option tag value on refreshing/submitting the page. But it is setting to maximum value of stock, here as '5'. With adding above code, it is actually giving me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: I corrected the code. I did forget some parens. For the maximum, I can say without seeing more of your code. $Quantity affectation is not shown.

Comment: Perfecto!!!.. It worked like a charm....:) Thank you very much for your time and help.... But there is another thing that value gets reset when I navigate through pages. Can you please guide me over this?

Comment: Resolved... I took it from db and stored it against `$_GET['quantity']`

Comment: I tried to UpVote your help but StackOverflow told me I don't have 15  reputation to do  so... I'm a newbie to SO. But I'll surely do.

Comment: Yeah right. I forgot to look your reputation, which is too low.

Comment: I am having issue with quantity update. Suppose, i have added two items (item A and item B). So when i try to update quantity for B, the GET method is taking selected quantity of A in the request. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: Three things : First, you shall ask a new question. Second, you shall accept this answer. Third, quickly I could tell you that you shall have one key per item : `$_GET['quantity-A']; $_GET['quantity-B'];`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.